# build.gradle not working. red underline but no linting errors

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, flutter, build.gradle

I have set up the standard flutter counter app in android studio. there are no linting errors however the app level build.gradle is underlined in red.

I am running android studio 3.5 latest stable build on windows 10.

I have tried reinstalling android studio.

UPDATE: Here is a screenshot of the error. There are no linting errors (fresh Flutter counter app project). But it is stuck on initializing gradle when building for android emulator: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w974A.png)

Comment: share your gradle file

Comment: Share your errors.

Comment: @MehulGohil it seems to be stuck on initializing gradle...

Comment: @ShivamOberoi it is just the standard gradle file created with flutter stable channel

Comment: It's normal and should not affect the build process.

Answer (score 1):

My Android Studio Version is 3.4.1.

In my project, your `GradleException` is `FileNotFoundException`.

Try to change it.

About `def localProperties = new Properties()`, I think your should download something use SDK Manager.

Just like Android SDK Platform-Tools,Android SDK Build-Tools and so on.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me nuts. Changing `GradleException` to `FileNotFoundException` worked like a charm!